# what is the difference between parent theme and child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

A client asked me to redesign her web site, built several years ago in WP by another developer. Although I've never worked with WP before, I'm pretty comfortable with html, css, and php, and I more or less understand how WP stores content and dynamically builds pages. But I'm wondering how to approach these challenges:

My client's site has about 75 pages. There are about 25 that are static (i.e. the content changes infrequently if at all; things like "about us" and "faqs") and there are about 50 pages that are more "blog-like", except that instead of posts, the content contains directory-type info (e.g. 12 DJs in the area) or event-related info (e.g. upcoming shows at local theaters). Both of these categories contain many sub (and sometimes sub-sub) categories (e.g. medical services > pediatric > kid allergy specialists) and the content updates fairly frequently.

I understand the difference in WP between "pages" and "posts". But I need to find out the best way to structure the static content. Should I just set up a parent/child hierarchy of pages, changing the permalinks to something that makes sense? Or is it better / easier to just build the static pages outside WP and somehow link to them from the common navigation?

As a web designer, I want to "wow" my client with a great design. While there are loads of wonderful WP themes available, I really need to create something unique. But I'm wary of breaking something, so what's the best way to take an existing theme and just tweak it enough to make it look a little different?

Finally, other than mounting a massive "copy and paste" effort when the new site is built, is there a way to transfer content from the original site to the new one?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation yet? [Child themes and Parent themes - WordPress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Comment: Also, if possible, I would avoid changing the permalink structure if this is a site that has been around for some time already as that might hurt the site's [SEO](https://moz.com/learn/seo/what-is-seo) if not done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Child Theme (https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme). And just do your changes in this theme.

You can download the complete Website with a plugin like duplicator and install it local (xampp).

Is hard to give you the right way. There are so many ways a theme can look like. Different page builder plugins or Advanced Custom Fields.

Maybe the only thing you can do, is to update (Theme, Plugin)everything and lift the page. Especially if it is a purchased theme with any page builder. But don't change anything in the main theme. Create a child theme!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the difference in WP between "pages" and "posts". But I
>   need to find out the best way to structure the static content. Should
>   I just set up a parent/child hierarchy of pages, changing the
>   permalinks to something that makes sense? Or is it better / easier to
>   just build the static pages outside WP and somehow link to them from
>   the common navigation?

It's not something like that. Consider the child theme as inherited (like a PHP class) from the parent theme. Imagine every .php file in a child theme is like overriding a function from parent class which is parent theme in this example.

For more information check the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) out or google "`wordpress theme vs child theme`" there are lots of articles explaining the difference.